# Desaparecer TextView con FireBase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo una app de notas con la cual trabajo con Firebase en java(Android Studio).Mi problema es que no se como implementar un `TextView` en medio de la pantalla principal que diga *"Ninguna nota"* cuando no existan notas en mi base de datos y que desaparezca ese mismo `TextView` cuando ya existan notas en la base de datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar y mostrarme un ejemplo de código para que pueda guiarme. No creo que sea necesario poner el código de mi `MainActivity`. Quiero ver ejemplos y así poder entender como poder implementar en mi código.

Comment: Prueba con `FrameLayout`.

Comment: podrias poner la estructura de tu base de datos en Firebase y el codigo que usas para hacer el request a la base de datos para pedir los textos ?

Answer (score 0):

Sin código , es dificil saber cual es tu problema, pero aca te dejo una forma de razonar el problema

Si tenes X textos adentro de una coleccion o un nodo de tu base de datos, seguramente usas un ciclo de repeticion `for(...)` para poder iterar y obtener todas las notas.

Existe un metodo en Firebase llamado [getChildrenCount()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()) este metodo te devuelve la cantidad de hijos en realtime database que tiene un cierto nodo.

Entonces, lo que haces es ir bajo esa referencia, usar [getChildrenCount()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()) para saber la cantidad de nodos que tenes, si esa cantidad es = 0 es por que no existen textos dentro de ese nodo, entonces ahi desde tu vista podes mostrar el texto

> "No existen mas textos".

La misma forma aplica para Firestore, nada mas que al no tener getChildrenCount() tenes que hacer un loop y obtener los documentos , despues podes comparar

### Snippet

```
db.collection("Textos").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int count = 0;
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                count++;
            }
            //Chequear con if si los documentos son mayor a 0
            if(count > 0) //no mostras el texto
            else
            // Mostras el texto
            Log.d("TAG", count + "");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error obteniendo documentos: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Si estas mostrando tus textos en una lista, podes usar el metodo `getItemCount()` de tu adaptador para preguntar si existen o no elementos para poner dentro de la lista, sino mostras un mensaje predeterminado